# Value set in the hidden field is not reflecting in document ready function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am not able to retrieve the values from hidden field. Sometimes I am getting values & sometimes its coming empty. Please assist.

Also let me know can we store a C# arraylist in a hiddenfield?
My HTML looks like this...

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSelectedContactID" value="@Model.Contact.ContactID" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSelectedAddressList" value="@Model.Contact.AddressList" />


$(document).ready(function () {
        _contactID = $("#hdnSelectedContactID").val();
        _addressList = $("#hdnSelectedAddressList").val();
}
```

After assigning a name to it in document.ready method, the outer html(in quick watch) appears like this...

```
outerHTML         "<INPUT id=hdnSelectedContactID type=hidden name=hdnSelectedContactID>"            String

outerHTML         "<INPUT id=hdnSelectedAddressList value=Dell.USP.Business.Models.TelephoneList type=hidden name=hdnSelectedAddressList>"       String
```

Comment: It would appear that the problem is server-side. Is your server always placing values in the elements' `value` attributes?

Comment: Yes, If I place debugger, I can see the value in coming in @Model.Contact.ContactID.

Comment: Does anything change the value of the hidden field after it's been initially loaded?

Comment: No, What I found is with MVC 3.0, may be input is not reliable to use. When I used html.hiddenfor(), it started working fine, everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a helper to insert a hidden field?

```
@Html.HiddenFor(h => h.ContactID)
```

You can't store an arraylist in a hiddenfield as an object, but you can insert the values of an arraylist in a hiddenfield with delimiters to seperate them. You turn it into a string and load it in the view.

Comment: I ve tried using HTML.Hidden("id", @Model.Contact.ContactID), but it was not working. Let me try HiddenFor now & chk...

Comment: Thx, Its started working now :).... I am able to access the value with id as ContactID. Any idea, if I ve another controld with the same name in design time, then how its going to resolve the issue?

Comment: I came to the conclusion that if there is another control with same lamda expression (For example my contactID & hidden contactID control both has the same h => h.ContactID expression), so I ve to add an extra id attribute, as @Html.HiddenFor(h => h.Contact.Title, new { id = "hdnContactID" } ). Else wrong value might get overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Addition: initialization of js-variable with ArrayList:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var _addressList = @Html.Raw(string.Format("['{0}']", string.Join("','", Model.Contact.AddressList.ToArray().Select(s => HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s.ToString())))));

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // test 
        alert(_addressList[0]);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extra note you CAN serialize your list into a hidden field using the MVCContrib Html.Serialize function. However this is basically for server side reuse again similar to viewstate

Answer (score 0):

First of all in MVC 3.0, always try to use its own controls from HTML helpers, like `@Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Contact.Title)`, instead of

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnSelectedContactID" value="@Model.Contact.ContactID" />
```

Also I came to the conclusion that if there is another control with same lamda expression (For example my contactID & hidden contactID control both has the same h => h.ContactID expression), I ve to add an extra "id" attribute, as 
`@Html.HiddenFor(h => h.Contact.Title, new { id = "hdnContactID" } )`. 
Else wrong value might get overridden.