# How to preserve a C# list in my view page, to manipulate that in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I m using ASP.Net MVC 3.0. My model has a list of telephone. I want to preserve that in some way, so that I can manipulate & display later using Jquery in my script.

I tried saving the list in a hidden field, but I am not able to retrieve that in my JavaScript.

Please help me finding a way out. Thx in advance.

Comment: How did you try to save it to a hidden field?  And how did you try to retrieve it?

Comment: Would it be possible to get the data for this list using jQuery `$.ajax()` calls, rather then trying to store the list in a cache?

Comment: If you're trying to use code similar to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130383/value-set-in-the-hidden-field-is-not-reflecting-in-document-ready-function), you're just not parsing the array properly in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property on your viewmodel which holds a json serialized version of the phonenumbers like this:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public IList<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
        public IHtmlString SerializedPhoneNumbers
        {
            get { return MvcHtmlString.Create(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(PhoneNumbers)); }
        }
    }
```

You can use that in the view like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var phoneNumbers = @Model.SerializedPhoneNumbers 
</script>
```

You now can manipulate the collection in your clientside script.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But its coming in the form of string in my script. But I want to deSerialize it to a Phone number list again. Any idea how to get it back?

Comment: You can manipulate the json clientside, to javascript it's not a string but an object. You can post the json back to the server using jquery ajax, the json modelbinder on the server side can recreate the viewmodel. I don't exactly know what your usecase is, hope this points you in the right direction.